# Save editable database table

Tags: mysql, database, insert

I'm currently working on editable database tables but how can I save it to the database?

This is the code to save all the rows:

```
function saveRow(oTable, nRow) {
   var jqInputs = $('input', nRow);
   oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[0].value, nRow, 0, false);
   oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[1].value, nRow, 1, false);
   oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[2].value, nRow, 2, false);
   oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[3].value, nRow, 3, false);
   oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[4].value, nRow, 4, false);
   oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[5].value, nRow, 5, false);
   oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[6].value, nRow, 6, false);
   oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[7].value, nRow, 7, false);
   oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[8].value, nRow, 8, false);
   oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[9].value, nRow, 9, false);
   oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>', nRow, 10, false);
   oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="proedit" href="">edit</a>', nRow, 11, false);
   oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="delete" href="">Delete</a>', nRow, 12, false);
   oTable.fnDraw();
}
```

Can someone show me a example how to save it to a database ?